# why DDR4 runs at 1867 by default when both motherboard and memory is 2133?

Tags: memory

On my Supermicro machine memory speed is set to Auto [image]
[Motherboard](http://www.supermicro.com/products/motherboard/xeon/c600/x10sri-f.cfm) supports 2133 MHz.
As you can see from output Samsung memory also supports 2133 MHz.
I was not intentionally configuring it to run at 1866 MHz.
But according to `dmidecode` it runs at 1866 MHz.

```
Handle 0x0059, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
Array Handle: 0x0058
Error Information Handle: Not Provided
Total Width: 72 bits
Data Width: 64 bits
Size: 8192 MB
Form Factor: DIMM
Set: None
Locator: DIMMA1
Bank Locator: P0_Node0_Channel0_Dimm0
Type: Other
Type Detail: Synchronous
Speed: 2133 MHz
Manufacturer: Samsung (date:14/4v)
Serial Number: 3552B798
Asset Tag: DIMMA1_AssetTag
Part Number: M393A1G40DB0-CPB   
Rank: 1
Configured Clock Speed: 1866 MHz
```

Any reasons for this? Is it safe to change it to run 2133 MHz? Should I change this somewhere in RHEL 7 or in BIOS?

Comment: You change it in BIOS and of course it's safe

Comment: thanks I just disabled "Enforce POR" and get frequency 2133.